# primefaces datatable header checkbox select row all of page

Tags: jsf, checkbox, primefaces, datatable, pagination

Selecting the records on every page of the table when I press the checkbox. Please Help me

```
<p:dataTable var="projectMaterial"  id="projectMaterial" paginator="true" paginatorAlwaysVisible="true" paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}" rows="12" rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,15" rowSelectMode="true" selection="#{pprMaterialAuthorizationBean.selectedMaterialList}" rowKey="#{projectMaterial.id}" value="#{pprMaterialAuthorizationBean.materialList}">
    <p:column  headerText="#{lang.labelMaterial}" filterBy="#{lang[projectMaterial.materialLangPrm]}" sortBy="#{lang[projectMaterial.materialLangPrm]}" width="40%">
        <h:outputText value="#{lang[projectMaterial.materialLangPrm]}" />
    </p:column>
    <p:ajax  event="toggleSelect" listener="#{pprMaterialAuthorizationBean.onToggleSelect}" update=":form1 :msgs"/> 
    <p:column id="columnId" selectionMode="multiple" width="40%"/>
</p:dataTable>
```

Comment: if you store the selection state in a managed bean `<p:dataTable selection="#{pprMaterialAuthorizationBean.selectedMaterialList}"...>` then it will store the state when you paging back and forth. if you don't want it, clear the list in the bean (`pprMaterialAuthorizationBean.selectedMaterialList`) in an actionListener (ajax/non-ajax).

Answer (score 0):

```
 <p:dataTable var="projectMaterial"  id="projectMaterial" 
                                         paginator="true" paginatorAlwaysVisible="true" paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"
                                         rows="12" rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,15" rowSelectMode="true"  
                                         selection="#{pprMaterialAuthorizationBean.selectedMaterialList}" rowKey="#{projectMaterial.id}"  
                                         value="#{pprMaterialAuthorizationBean.materialList}" >

                                <p:column  headerText="#{lang.labelMaterial}" filterBy="#{lang[projectMaterial.materialLangPrm]}" sortBy="#{lang[projectMaterial.materialLangPrm]}" width="40%">
                                    <h:outputText value="#{lang[projectMaterial.materialLangPrm]}" />
                                </p:column>
                                <p:ajax event="toggleSelect" listener="#{pprMaterialAuthorizationBean.selectAllFalas}" update=":form1:projectMaterial"/>
                                <p:column selectionMode="multiple" width="40%"/>
 </p:dataTable>


public void selectAllFalas() {
            if(selectAllFalas == false) {
                selectedMaterialList = (List<HydPipeMaterial>) materialList;
                selectAllFalas = true;
            }else{
                selectedMaterialList = new ArrayList<>();
                selectAllFalas = false;
            }
        }
```